# Pegado automatico en Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Tengo una Mac y cada vez que busco alguna palabra o algo en Sublime Text (con 'cmd+f'), se me pega automáticamente un texto que alguna vez copie.

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si vas al finder, Edición, Mostrar portapapeles ¿que te sale? ¿ese texto viejo que dices o lo último que has copiado?

Comment: @marc me sale lo ultimo que copie, no lo que se copia solo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor será resetear el portapapeles te dejo un enlace de alguien con el mismo problema. Está en inglés: (https://danwarne.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/fix-stuck-mac-os-clipboard-copypaste/)

Comment: No me di cuenta que que solamente pasaba en Sublime Text (edito pregunta). Había que resolverlo borrando el portapapeles de Sublime. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas arreglado.